# Changing normal distribution given new data

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

[image]

Assume as in the  picture above, we have two points $A$ and $B$. Each has a location with a normal distribution of error, i.e. $A$ is believed to be at $x=0$ with an error of $σ=1$, and $B$ at $x=35$ with an error of $σ=1$.

Point $A$ now knows that it is only $33$ meters (exactly) away from point $B$.

1. How would this affect the normal distribution of error of point $A$?

   What would also happen to the distribution if the $33$ meters has a margin of error?

Comment: What is your attempt?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: I am a  bit naive in statistics i tried to come up with new distribution with a mean = previous mean(0 ) + the difference(35-33).
I failed to understand the way I should combine the two distributions in order to come up with the new one.
I believe that the distribution should be skewed and not normal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can represent the joint probability distribution as in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rq9k1.png) above.
Having a relation d=x-y can be represented on the joint distribution by straight line with the more probable position presented as the projection of the center on the line.[as represented here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hp3ML.png)
The error of the distance can be represented by making the line thick.